# get scale of image (px/cm^2) in pydicom

Tags: dicom, pydicom

I have multiple ultrasound images in dicom file. I need to extract information about scale of the image, i.e pixels/cm^2. Is there any dicom tag containing following information? Or should I calculate it somehow. My dicom file looks as following:

```
Dataset.file_meta -------------------------------
(0002, 0000) File Meta Information Group Length  UL: 196
(0002, 0001) File Meta Information Version       OB: b'\x00\x01'
(0002, 0002) Media Storage SOP Class UID         UI: Ultrasound Multi-frame Image Storage
(0002, 0003) Media Storage SOP Instance UID      UI: 1.2.840.113619.2.391.51208.1686298501.4.21
(0002, 0010) Transfer Syntax UID                 UI: JPEG Baseline (Process 1)
(0002, 0012) Implementation Class UID            UI: 1.2.276.0.48.20000.2
(0002, 0013) Implementation Version Name         SH: 'TomTecArena v2'
(0002, 0016) Source Application Entity Title     AE: 'TTCLIENT'
-------------------------------------------------
(0008, 0008) Image Type                          CS: ['DERIVED', 'PRIMARY', '', '0001']
(0008, 0016) SOP Class UID                       UI: Ultrasound Multi-frame Image Storage
(0008, 0018) SOP Instance UID                    UI: 1.2.840.113619.2.391.51208.1686298501.4.21
(0008, 0020) Study Date                          DA: '20230609'
(0008, 0021) Series Date                         DA: '20230609'
(0008, 0023) Content Date                        DA: '20230609'
(0008, 002a) Acquisition DateTime                DT: '20230609081459'
(0008, 0030) Study Time                          TM: '081459'
(0008, 0031) Series Time                         TM: '081459'
(0008, 0033) Content Time                        TM: '081459'
(0008, 0050) Accession Number                    SH: ''
(0008, 0060) Modality                            CS: 'US'
(0008, 0070) Manufacturer                        LO: 'GE Vingmed Ultrasound'
(0008, 0090) Referring Physician's Name          PN: ''
(0008, 1090) Manufacturer's Model Name           LO: 'Vivid E95'
(0008, 2142) Start Trim                          IS: '1'
(0008, 2143) Stop Trim                           IS: '32'
(0008, 2144) Recommended Display Frame Rate      IS: '30'
(0010, 0010) Patient's Name                      PN: '3001'
(0010, 0020) Patient ID                          LO: '3001'
(0010, 0030) Patient's Birth Date                DA: ''
(0010, 0040) Patient's Sex                       CS: ''
(0012, 0062) Patient Identity Removed            CS: 'YES'
(0012, 0063) De-identification Method            LO: 'GEVU anonymization'
(0018, 0040) Cine Rate                           IS: '30'
(0018, 0072) Effective Duration                  DS: '1.04'
(0018, 1020) Software Versions                   LO: 'Vivid E95:201.84.0'
(0018, 1063) Frame Time                          DS: '33.5484'
(0018, 1066) Frame Delay                         DS: '0.0'
(0018, 1088) Heart Rate                          IS: '95'
(0018, 1242) Actual Frame Duration               IS: '33'
(0018, 1244) Preferred Playback Sequencing       US: 0
(0018, 6011)  Sequence of Ultrasound Regions  1 item(s) ---- 
   (0018, 6012) Region Spatial Format               US: 1
   (0018, 6014) Region Data Type                    US: 1
   (0018, 6016) Region Flags                        UL: 0
   (0018, 6018) Region Location Min X0              UL: 213
   (0018, 601a) Region Location Min Y0              UL: 70
   (0018, 601c) Region Location Max X1              UL: 803
   (0018, 601e) Region Location Max Y1              UL: 658
   (0018, 6020) Reference Pixel X0                  SL: 295
   (0018, 6022) Reference Pixel Y0                  SL: 0
   (0018, 6024) Physical Units X Direction          US: 3
   (0018, 6026) Physical Units Y Direction          US: 3
   (0018, 602c) Physical Delta X                    FD: 0.0238278
   (0018, 602e) Physical Delta Y                    FD: 0.0238278
   (0018, 6030) Transducer Frequency                UL: 1670
   ---------
(0018, 6060) R Wave Time Vector                  FL: [313.3869934082031, 1000.0260009765625]
(0020, 000d) Study Instance UID                  UI: 1.2.840.113619.2.391.51208.1686298500.4.1
(0020, 000e) Series Instance UID                 UI: 1.2.840.113619.2.391.51208.1686298500.4.2
(0020, 0010) Study ID                            SH: '202306090814'
(0020, 0011) Series Number                       IS: '1'
(0020, 0013) Instance Number                     IS: '19'
(0020, 0020) Patient Orientation                 CS: ''
(0028, 0002) Samples per Pixel                   US: 3
(0028, 0004) Photometric Interpretation          CS: 'YBR_FULL_422'
(0028, 0006) Planar Configuration                US: 0
(0028, 0008) Number of Frames                    IS: '32'
(0028, 0009) Frame Increment Pointer             AT: (0018, 1063)
(0028, 0010) Rows                                US: 708
(0028, 0011) Columns                             US: 1016
(0028, 0014) Ultrasound Color Data Present       US: 0
(0028, 0100) Bits Allocated                      US: 8
(0028, 0101) Bits Stored                         US: 8
(0028, 0102) High Bit                            US: 7
(0028, 0103) Pixel Representation                US: 0
(0028, 2110) Lossy Image Compression             CS: '01'
(0028, 2112) Lossy Image Compression Ratio       DS: '95.0'
(7fe0, 0010) Pixel Data                          OB: Array of 2521450 elements
(fffc, fffc) Data Set Trailing Padding           OB: b'\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partially you can calculate that. Note that the acquisition technique of US uses a cone beam, hence pixel size usually varies across the image. But depending on your application, I would say that the contents of the Sequence of Ultrasound Regions (0018, 6011) is your friend:

- (0018, 6018) - (0018, 601e) are telling you the rectangular area in pixels in which the measurements are applicable. Note that it is only a part in the center of the image
- (0018, 6024) and (0018, 6026) are telling you that the physical units in this area is cm (0x0003h)
- and (0018, 602c), (0018, 602e) are telling you that the pixels are squares, and their dimensions are 0.0238278 x 0.0238278 cm

See [here](https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/us-image/us-region-calibration/00186011) for reference